# Breaking out of nested if

Tags: java, if-statement, break, nested-if

I have a bit of code that contains nested if statements:

```
if(numberOfNeighbors == 1){

                //go through comparison again, add Pixel(i,j) to current linked list -> complist[numberOfComponents]
                    //  break out of large check ??

                    if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i-1,j-1))){ //compare to top left
                        complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break; 
                    }
                    if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i,j-1))){ // compare to top
                        complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                    }

                    if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i+1,j-1))){ // compare to top right
                        complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                    }
                    if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i-1,j))){ // compare to left
                        complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                    }
} // end of if(numberOfNeighbors == 1)
```

Basically what I would like to do, however inefficient this may be, is compare a something 4 times, but if it turns out it is a match, break out of the set of the 4 nested if statements, as well as the outer if statement.

Will this work? or will it just break out of the nested if its currently at and continue to the next until its gone through all 4?

Answer (score 9):

**IMPORTANT: `break` statements are used to come out of loops but not branches**

I understood your question but use `break` statement to go out of loops like `for`, `while`, `do while`. You can go out of `if` statement when the condition is satisfied and statements inside the `if` branch are executed. If you don't want to check for other conditions when your first `if` is satisfied you have to use `if else` branches instead of using 4 if statements.
These two links might be useful

- [if else document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)
- [break document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

See the below example

```
if(condition) {
    if(condition) { //if this evaluates to true, logic1 is executed
        logic1;
    }
    else if(condition) { //if the above condition fails, but this condition satisfies then logic 2 is executed
        logic2;
    }
    else { //if the above 2 conditions fail, you can execute logic3
        logic3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `else`?

```
if(numberOfNeighbors == 1){

            //go through comparison again, add Pixel(i,j) to current linked list -> complist[numberOfComponents]
                //  break out of large check ??

                if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i-1,j-1))){ //compare to top left
                    complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break; 
                }
                else if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i,j-1))){ // compare to top
                    complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                }

                else if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i+1,j-1))){ // compare to top right
                    complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                }
                else if(ji.getPixelColor(i, j) == (ji.getPixelColor(i-1,j))){ // compare to left
                    complist[numberOfComponents].addFirst(new Pixel(i,j,numberOfComponents)); break;
                }
} // end of if(numberOfNeighbors == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

break; does NOT work for if statements, only loops, switch and such.

You can do this to avoid nesting:

```
if(mainCondition)
{
  if(condition1)
    goto LabelContinue;

  bool condition2 = logic...;

  if(condition2)
    goto LabelContinue;

  //Code
}
LabelContinue:
//Other code.
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do this. This is not 1985.

Comment: It Is Java, There's No Goto Statement!